# Common connectionstrings across all the sites

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

I have multiple sites created on single server. IIS 7 is installed. And All these sites have same connectionstrings. But these are defined in their respective web.config file.

I want to remove these connectionstrings from all the web.config files and set at common location wither in machine.config or some other config file so that all the sites will access the same. Both these applications has different root config files.

1. C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\web.config
2. C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\web.config

Please suggest on this.

Comment: machine.config is the way to go

Comment: We tried to set the connectionstrings at server level in iis. But we are not able to read the same in .net application. Can you just elaborate the same, plz.

Comment: There is 2 machine.config, one for 32 bits app and one for 64 bits app. Are you sure you modified the correct one ? if this was the case, could you share some code ?

Comment: let me check. but how can we identify whether to edit 32 or 64 bit

Comment: machine.config files are not on the same folder C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\ for 32 bits and C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\ for 64 bits

Comment: Can you just confirm that if we add a connectionstring from iis at server level (config editor). Then that will change the respective machine.config file.

Comment: No, the iis root file is `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config` but it should works the same way.

Comment: We add a connectionstring from iis at server level (config editor). But I could not see the same in any of the config file (machine.config /  applicationhost.config / administration.config). Can you tell me which config file is updated by system for this configuration.

Comment: I though it was the applicationHost.config file but after test it the master web.config file located near the machine.config (`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config`). See [ASP.NET Configuration File Hierarchy and Inheritance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685(v=vs.140).aspx) for more information about config file inheritance

Comment: The fact is on the server I could not find any config file with connectionstring settings that I added at server level. So now trying for the WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration.

Thanks Cyril. Atleast I could check the existing config files are actually changed or not with your help.

Comment: `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["test"].ConnectionString` should be enough due to configuration file inheritance (except if you have a `</clear>` somewhere on your inheritance)

Comment: One more thing I found is, 1 application's is pointing to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\ and other is poitning to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\.

But I should be changing single config file for connectionstring and both applications should be able to read it.

Any idea?

Comment: Added a new question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30890074/framework64-and-framework