# Framework64 and Framework

Tags: asp.net

There are 2 applications pointing to 2 different paths.
 1. C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\web.config 
 2. C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\web.config

I want to keep my connection strings in 1 single file so that both the applications should be able to read the same.

Any idea?

Comment: How about not storing your application configuration in the framework installation directory? The configurations there are basic configurations for all applications. Don't write application-specific configuration values in there. Put a web.config in your application root.

Comment: We have multiple applications, and all applications have same connectionstring. Any suggestion. Few in classic asp and few in .net

Comment: You may want to [edit your existing question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30863535/common-connectionstrings-across-all-the-sites).

Comment: Edited the same. Can anyone answer this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to store your connection strings in external .config file and include it in both web.config files. Here is how to export profile configuration into a dedicated configuration file.
This is web.config:

```
...
  <system.web>
    ...
    <profile configSource="profile.config" />
    ...
  </system.web>
...
```

This is profile.config:

```
<profile>
  <properties>
    <add name="Name" type="String" />
    <add name="Age" type="Int32" />
  </properties>
</profile>
```

Make sure you use .config as the extension of your files so they cannot be served to the browser.

[See this blog post for details](http://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/using-configsource-to-split-configuration-files)

To use one .config file in multiple applications create a symbolic link to that file in each application folder and reference that link in web config. Use mklink command in elevated command prompt:

```
cd "c:\YourApplicationDirectoryWhereWebConfigIs"
mklink profile.config "c:\YourSharedConfigFilesDirectory\profile.config"
```

Comment: I want to have the config file outside the application folder not in the subfolders.

Comment: Just create a symbolic link to that file in each application folder and reference that link in web config. Use mklink command in elevated command prompt: mklink profile.config "c:\MySharedPath\profile.config"